# Collection.loadTable: not found in GEE

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

When I tried to upload my .shp file in Google Earth Engine Asset and import in Python like this:
**self.TS_POP = ee.FeatureCollection(users/arafayknysys/pop_TS)**
And when I tried to load the Geometric Data using **self.TS_POP.getInfo()**, I get the following error:
Collection.loadTable: (*) not found
Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by my self, Actually what I have done is after uploading my dataset in Google Earth Engine code editor. I forgot to give the read access to every one.
**Steps**:
Just goto the Asset tab of JavaScript Code editor.
Click on the Asset name as mine is TS_POP.
Then Share it and click the checkbox **'Anyone can read'**.
Then click on Done.[image]