# how to upload parameter in Google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to  upload parameter for  temperature retrieval. Now I get this parameter with csv, but  when  I  try to load this csv with  fusion table like

```
var fc=ee.FeatureCollection('fc:1Y572nUj-nkXAUwe-pDWRj0_s5ZBN4DEOkih-XfBC')
```

I get

> Collection.loadTable: Collection asset 'fc:1Y572nUj-nkXAUwe-pDWRj0_s5ZBN4DEOkih-XfBC' not found.

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please refer if this resolves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036103/collection-loadtable-not-found-in-gee

Comment: I try it  .But  it  do not  work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by my self.
so easy.

> var fc=ee.FeatureCollection('fc:1Y572nUj-nkXAUwe-pDWRj0_s5ZBN4DEOkih-XfBC')`

instead of

> var fc=ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1PYuL9IdqwvzRoSrtLVe2dCsQ1sxB1wHv_W5iIkU_')